# Asp.net MVC 5 : CRUD in modal dialog using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5, crud

I 'm newebie in Asp.net MVC 5
So , I have a simple project in which i'm usiong asp.net . I have an object named : 
`Object { Id, Code, Name}` .

I want to list the Objects in grid , edit , add and remove . 
I am able to show the list and add new object .
Those operations are in modal dialog . 
I have some problems now :

1. **How to send the Object** to the action Controller then show it or edit itinto a modal dialog using javascript when i choose it ?

[image]

2. The second picture is when i click **add new Object** , it shows me the modal dialog , and all works fine with the Add , biut not with the others actions.

[image]

> My Code

- ObjectController :

  ```
      public ActionResult AddObject()
      {
         if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
             return PartialView(dd);
         return View(dd);
      }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult AddObject(ModelObject model)
  {
      /* Working Code */

  }
  ```
- AddObject partial View :

  ```
          @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddObject", "Object",
              new AjaxOptions
              {
                  HttpMethod = "POST",
                  UpdateTargetId = "msgAdd",
                  OnSuccess = "addSuccess",
                  OnFailure = "addFailure"
              },
              new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
          {
              @Html.ValidationSummary(true);

              <div class="row" style="padding: 5px 0 5px 0">
                  <div class="col-lg-12">

                      <div class="col-lg-12 border no-margin" style="padding:10px 0px 10px 0 !important">
                          <div class="form-group" style="align-content:center">

                              <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Code  </label>
                              <div class="col-lg-6">
                                  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Code, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Code" })
                                  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Code)
                              </div>
                              <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Libellé  </label>
                              <div class="col-lg-6">
                                  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Libellé " })
                                  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
                              </div>
                          </div>

                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="hr-line-solid no-margin"></div>
              <div class="row" style="padding: 5px 0 5px 0">
                  <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-4">
                      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline btn-primary"><i class="icon-refresh icon-white"></i> Réinitialiser</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-4">
                      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default right" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
                      <input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" class="btn btn-success right" />
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div id="msgAdd" style="display:none">

              </div>
          }

      </div>
  ```
- ListObjects View :

  ```
    <tbody>
     @foreach (var m in Model.objects)
         {  
  <tr class="gradeX">
  <td id="idObject" style="display:none;"><span class="hideextra">@m.Id</span></td>
    <td><span class="hideextra">@m.Code</span></td>
    <td><span class="hideextra">@m.Name</span></td>

    <td class="infont">
        <center>
            <a id="btnEdit"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o text-"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash-o text-danger"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search text-navy"></i></a>
        </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
  }
  </tbody>
  ```
- Javascript :
  1- For adding :

  $(document).ready(function () {
              //jQuery.noConflict();
              $("#btn").click(function () {
                  var url = "AddObject"; // the url to the controller
                  $.get(url, function (data) {
                      $("#saisieJDiag").draggable({
                          handle: ".modal-header"
                      });
                      $("#saisieJDiag").resizable();
                      $("#saisieJDiag").html(data);
                      $("#saisieJDiag").modal("show");

  ```
                  $('#saisieJDiag').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                      $('.chosen-select', this).chosen();
                  });
                  $('.i-checks').iCheck({
                      checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
                      radioClass: 'iradio_square-green',
                  });
              });

          });
      });
  </script>
  ```

Now I want the same approch but to edit and show the obecjt on the modal , how i can do that !

Comment: It looks like you simply have a typo in the `@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddObecjt", "Obecjt",` that should be `@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddObject", "Object",` instead -- as the names must match.

Comment: @DavidPine It was a mistake when i have doing some change  to simplify